# Trying to access HTTP REST client pluggin from firefox using selenium webdriver. Getting a weird error

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, frames

I am trying to access the Headers drop down in the REST Client page(Firefox RESTClient plugin). The test case is failing at that point saying 
"org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it"

I am using Xpath to get the webElement. I do not see an issue with the Xpath. Also not sure why it is saying the Element belongs to a different frame when there is no frame at all in that page.
I checked the page source and no frame tags in the HTML. How else do I know if a page contains a frames?

The Xpath I am using for getting the Headers webElement is //a[contains(text(),'Headers')]

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, your Xpath causes the issue.I don't find any the Anchor tag Headers.

Try the following , both worked for me.

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Extensions')]")
```

or

```
By.linkText("Extensions")
```

You can find the full source from [here](https://gist.github.com/kalakkumkarthikeyan/e0bfca45b777b6697c66)

Please let me know, does this solves your issue.

Comment: I saw your code in github. You are accessing "addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/";. This works. But I am not trying this. Here is my code snippet  `driver.get("chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html"); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Header‌​s')]"))); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Headers')]"));` 
This doesn't work and I get that error

Answer (score 0):

you can't send string to pass at API link but can move through page via below robot class code.

```
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);


        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_P);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_L);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

      //  r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
       // r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
```